# Android Listview inside CoordinatorLayout how to make it scroll-able?

Tags: android, listview

I have listactivity.java which has code like below. Note it uses 
activity_main_listapps1.xml and listview_layout files.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_listapps1);

String[] from = { "flag","label","cur" ,"right_flag"};

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur,R.id.right_flag};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where activity_main_listapps1.xml is :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_design_support_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and listview_layout.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="hello"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cur"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="hello"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This code is not scroll able. I tried adding android:layout_height to match_parent..something still missing.

Comment: remove ur listview from appbar layout, and write it outside appbarlayout, also write it inside the nested scroll view inside the coordinate layout.

Comment: after that add app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your listview

Comment: thanks, I removed & placed the listview outside appbarlayout. Now its scrollable.. will try other two suggestions regarding scroll-view and layout_behavior

Comment: It looks great now. I moved listview outside appbarlayout  & added app:layout_behavior. It works fine now :) please move this comment to answer. thank you

Comment: the other two suggestion are for kitkat, since the scroll will be slow in kitkat and below version, so u should use it inside the nested scroll view, and but the behavior as scrolling_view_behavior

Comment: okay sure, will add them too. (make your comments as answer , so that I can accept them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove your listview from appbar layout, and write it outside appbarlayout, also write it inside the nested scroll view inside the coordinate layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_design_support_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
            <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
      <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: A ListView inside a ScrollView (even NestedScrollView) is not a good idea. (one scrollable view inside another scrollable view).  Also, I tested a case likt this and my ListView showed just one element.